# A doubt in understanding the non uniform circular motion

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

Consider a particle undergoing a non uniform circular motion with a constant tangential acceleration. It is known that at any instant of the trajectory the acceleration of the particle has two components;one along the tangent to the circle and another along the radius of the circle. But when we will consider the velocities of the particle at two different instants(say t and t+dt) and if we make the quantity (dt) approach 0 then the speed of the particle at the two different instants will also approach 0. And the difference between the velocities of the particle at the two instants will become perpendicular to the velocity at time 't'. So the direction of the net acceleration will also become perpendicular to the velocity at time 't'. 
But it is contradicting our assumption that the particle is undergoing a non uniform circular motion. I am posting a picture to make my argument more clear.
[image]

Please help me figure out where I am getting wrong.

Comment: Look at it again . Is the dv vector which you have drawn is really the $V_{f} -V_{i}$ vector?. Remember parallelogram law of vectors.

Comment: Also it is always wise to first draw d$\theta$ as a big angle then use conditions .

Comment: @Abhinav It will be helpful if you please explain me a bit.

Comment: in your picture for dv the two vector v are of equal length, but since you have a tangential acceleration, they ar not, you can always draw dy in tangential and radial direction.

Comment: Look at the complete circle which you have drawn . Try drawing the ∆v vector. Does it point towards the centre of the circle. Now look at your small diagram. Shouldn't the dv vector have a component towards the centre?